# Can a Non-Epic character use an Epic Item?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, epic-tier

I am having trouble finding a rule that says anything about restrictions with epic magic Items being used by non-epic characters. That's it I just wanted to know if there is some rule in a legit book about that. If you could list the book and page number that would be great.

Comment: I'm just asking whether or not a level twenty character or below can use an epic level item by standard rules? Is there a rule that specifically says that a character that is not level 21 or above can't use an epic magic item.

Comment: O, I know! It's just easier to eliminate exceptions when the specific situation's detailed. I mean, *Can a* +1 [fiery blast](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/epicMagicItems.html#fiery-blast) greatsword *be wielded by a level 15 fighter?* is a much less sweeping question that gets the same general answer without an answer having to accommodate a host of possible exceptions. (Honestly, I'm not trying to give you a hard time or anything!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## A non-epic creature can employ an epic magic item

Neither the *Epic Level Handbook* (2002) on Epic Magic Items (123-50), the more recent *SRD* section on [Epic Magic Items](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/epicMagicItems.html), the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2012), nor the *Magic Item Compendium* (2013) in its handful of references to the *Epic Level Handbook* mentions any *general prohibition* against the use of epic magic items by non-epic creatures. Epic magic items have more prerequisites for their creation than their non-epic counterparts, and one epic magic item can easily exceed the entire expected wealth by level of a non-epic PC, but—so far as I'm aware—no rule *prevents* a non-epic creature that somehow acquires an epic magic item from *using* that epic magic item if the creature should otherwise be able to: the magic item's epicness… epicity… epicitude… *that the magic item's epic* is merely a classification based on, for example, the magic item's market price or total enhancement bonuses. Classifying the magic item as *epic* doesn't usually have an impact on *how*, *if*, or *for whom (or what)* the item functions.

(Some creatures may—by virtue of their statistics or class choices or Use Magic Device skill bonuses,—find some epic magic items (like, for example, [epic scrolls](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/epicMagicItemsOther.html#epic-scrolls)) very difficult or impossible to use, of course!)

Comment: @ObliviousSage The game uses *nonepic* without the hyphen: "The process of creating an epic magic item is very similar to creating a **nonepic** magic item" (*EL* 124) (emphasis mine), but I'm good with whatever's more readable.

Comment: We can double-check with English.SE if it comes to that, but I believe that a hyphen is necessary when adding the "non" prefix to a word. I certainly find it more readable myself.

Comment: @ObliviousSage *You* can. I expect support for that position to be nonexistent, the majority being nonplussed by your insistence. Either way, it doesn't matter: the *game* omits the hyphen… and omits periods in *AC*, capitalizes *Hit Dice*, and italicizes spells and magic items; it's kind of allowed to break rules. I'm going to leave this be for readability, but your insistence sounds like this is a Meta question for here rather than an English question.

Comment: Epic items existed before the epic rules were even made... they were called artifacts in the DMG and SRD.