# Is there a limit to fixed-price magic item properties?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, house-rules

I have a level 17 Psion Shaper, who has a suit of armor that is, I believe overpowered. I have followed all of the rules, the armor has not gone over +10 on the pricing table and the rest of it is gold piece enchantments. Is there a limit to how many enchantments you can place on a piece of armor; if they are simple gold piece cost enchantments? When the total pricing goes over 200,000 gold pieces, should I begin to multiply the cost by 10? I am having trouble finding out what to do, this is the complete list of my characters armor.

**Enhancement Bonus:**

+2 to AC.

**Ability Bonus:**

Fortification Heavy: +5 ability.

Invulnerability: +3 ability.

**Gold Piece Cost Enchantments:**

Greater Acid resistance: 66,000 gp.

Greater Cold resistance: 66,000 gp.

Greater Electricity resistance: 66,000 gp.

Greater Fire resistance: 66,000 gp.

Greater Sonic resistance: 66,000 gp.

Etherealness: 49,000 gp.

Undead Controlling: 49,000 gp.

Greater Slick: 33,750 gp.

Greater Shadow: 33,750 gp.

Greater Silent: 33,750 gp.

Glamered: 2,700 gp.

**Material:**

Mithral (Includes Masterwork): 4,000 gp.

Breastplate: 200 gp.

**Total:** 636,150 gp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A single suit of armor or shield cannot have a modified bonus (enhancement bonus plus property bonus equivalents) higher than +10, nor can it have a market price (not counting special materials or the price of the masterwork armor or shield itself) of greater than 200,000 gp. For armor or shields that exceed these limits, see *Epic Level Handbook*.

<sup>(*Magic Item Compendium*, pg. 6)</sup>

> In general, an item with even one of these characteristics is an epic magic item.
>
> [...]
>
> - Has a market price above 200,000 gp, not including material costs for armor or weapons, material component- or experience point-based costs, or additional value for intelligent items.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Market Price
>
> Use the guidelines for nonepic magic items to determine the market price of an epic magic item, with one addition: If the item gives a bonus beyond the limit allowed in for normal, nonepic magic items, multiply the portion of the market price derived from that characteristic by 10. Some epic characteristics, such as caster level, don’t trigger this multiplier.

<sup>([Epic Rules > Epic Magic Items](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/magicItems/basics.htm))</sup>

So while your item of greater than 200,000 gp in value is an epic item under the rules (and thus illegal unless the epic rules are in play), it does not require you to pay the ×10 premium so long as the things it does aren’t themselves epic, just a combination of a large number of sub-epic enhancements and properties. And [a non-epic character can use an epic item](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/92544/4563), if he has somehow acquired one. Note that 631,950 gp constitutes *over 90%* of the wealth expected for a 20th-level character, and is worth far more than a lower-level character is expected to have in total. Barring a preposterously generous game granting wealth far in excess of recommendations, it would never be a good idea to invest such a high percentage of one’s wealth in a single item.

Comment: What do you mean "(and thus illegal unless the epic rules are in play)"?

Comment: @Craigamore *Epic Level Handbook* is not a core book. It is not an assumed part of the base game. A given DM can easily decide not to include it in a given game. And as stated in *Magic Item Compendium*, a magic item “cannot have [...] a market price [...] of greater than 200,000 gp.” Unless *Epic Level Handbook* is in play, there are no rules that say otherwise and allow more expensive items to exist.

Comment: Epic Level Rules are actually part of the DMG, btw. Thus it IS part of the base game (at least the DMG version of the Epic rules is). Though, to be fair, it doesn't include rules on epic magic items, so this is more of a quibble than a counter.

Comment: @nijineko They are a *variant* in *Dungeon Master’s Guide*. They are not presumed to be functioning in any given campaign, but only apply if the DM says they are. And I strongly recommend all DMs say they aren’t, because the epic rules are terrible.

Comment: @KRyan Actually, those rules are not variant rules. The words *variant* or *optional* do not appear anywhere in the text for the Epic rules. I just checked. Those are the **default standard rules as written** for when a 20th level character becomes 21st. Page 206 - 210, not a single instance of variant or optional to be had. Sorry, but them be the RAW epic rules. SRD seems to concur.